# progress bar/dialog while sending data to json

Tags: android

I'm new on android and I want to display a progress bar while I'm sending data to my API and when the app finish to send data the progress bar dismiss.

I'm not sure how to implement the progress with the code that I have.
Please some help?

Here is the code I'm using to send data to my API:

```
    sendDataBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                    RequestModel data = helper.sendData(Integer.parseInt(imt));
                    request = new ApiRequest(MainActivity.this, APIMethod.POST, data);

                    try {
                        String response = request.execute("myURL").get();

                        ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel(response);

                        if (responseModel.isSuccess()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    });
```

Comment: avoid `get`, won't be execute as a asynchronous method

Answer (score 0):

```
<ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
   style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

In java:
    private ProgressBar spinner;
    spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

TO run your progress:
spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

To stop your progress:
spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: That's not why I'm asking for. it has to show only while I'm sending the data.

Comment: Then extend async task in your applicationsl

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AsyncTask to do that. While you are processing your code inside the OnClickListener you are using the main thread, so the UI will be blocked during the execution, so with an AsyncTask your code will be executed on an another background thread.

You can create a listener:

```
public interface AsyncTaskListener {
     void onStart();
     void onSuccess();
     void onError(Exception ex);
}
```

Your AsyncTask class:

```
public class CustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, CustomAsyncTask.ProcessingResult> {
    private AsyncTaskListener mListener;

    public CustomAsyncTask (AsyncTaskListener aListener) {
        mListener = aListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
         mListener.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected CustomAsyncTask.ProcessingResult doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        RequestModel data = helper.sendData(params[0]);
        request = new ApiRequest(MainActivity.this, APIMethod.POST, data);

        try {
            String response = request.execute("myURL").get();
            ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel(response);

            if (responseModel.isSuccess()) {
                return new ProcessingResult();
            } else {
                return new ProcessingResult(new Exception("Error message"));
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException|ExecutionException  e) {
            return new ProcessingResult(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ProcessingResult aResult) {
        Exception error = aResult.getError();
        if(error == null){
            mListener.onError(error);
        } else {
            mListener.onSuccess();
        }
    }

    private class ProcessingResult {
        private Exception mError;

        ProcessingResult () {

        }

        ProcessingResult (Exception aError) {
            mError = aError;
        }

        Exception getError() {
            return mError;
        }
    }
}
```

Add to your layout XML:

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressBar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Your activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        Button yourButton = findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
        yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CustomAsyncTask asyncTask = new CustomAsyncTask(new CustomListener());
                asyncTask.execute(Integer.parseInt(your_integer));
            }
        });
    }

    private class CustomListener implements AsyncTaskListener {
        public void onStart() {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void onSuccess() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        public void onError(Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```